# changing decimal number to text in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, decimal

I have written a function in asp.net to convert the decimal number to text format. IT works correctly except for the part after the decimal point. Any soonest help would be highly appreciated. Below in my code snippet:

```html
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl_num.Text = "";
            string amt = "80434.08";
            decimal num = Convert.ToDecimal(amt);
             lbl_num.Text = SpellDecimal(num);
        }



        public static string SpellDecimal(decimal number)
        {
            string[] digit =
               {
                     "", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", 
                     "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", 
                     "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", 
                     "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" 
               };

            string[] baseten = 
               {
                     "", "", "twenty", "thirty", "fourty", "fifty", 
                     "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" 
               };

            string[] expo = 
               { 
                     "", "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion",
                     "quadrillion", "quintillion"
               };

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int thousands = 0;
            decimal power = 1;

            if (number < 0)
            {
                sb.Append("minus ");
                number = -number;
            }

            decimal n = Decimal.Truncate(number);
            decimal cents = Decimal.Truncate((number - n) * 100);

            if (n == Decimal.Zero)
                sb.Append("zero");

            for (decimal i = n; i >= 1000; i /= 1000)
            {
                power *= 1000;
                thousands++;
            }

            bool sep = false;
            for (decimal i = n; thousands >= 0; i %= power, thousands--, power /= 1000)
            {
                int j = (int)(i / power);
                int k = j % 100;
                int hundreds = j / 100;
                int tens = j % 100 / 10;
                int ones = j % 10;

                if (j == 0)
                    continue;

                if (hundreds > 0)
                {
                    if (sep)
                        sb.Append(", ");

                    sb.Append(digit[hundreds]);
                    sb.Append(" hundred");
                    sep = true;
                }

                if (k != 0)
                {
                    if (sep)
                    {
                        sb.Append(" and ");
                        sep = false;
                    }

                    if (k < 20)
                        sb.Append(digit[k]);
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append(baseten[tens]);
                        if (ones > 0)
                        {
                            sb.Append("-");
                            sb.Append(digit[ones]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (thousands > 0)
                {
                    sb.Append(" ");
                    sb.Append(expo[thousands]);
                    sep = true;
                }
            }

            sb.Append(" and ");
            if (cents < 10) sb.Append("0");
            sb.Append(cents);
            sb.Append("/100");

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

It gives me the following output
eighty thousand, four hundred and thirty-four and 08/100
instead of
eighty thousand, four hundred and thirty-four point zero eight

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = ((decimal)yourNumber).ToString();
//if yourNumber = 1.1234
var d = (1.1234).ToString();
```

Just use `toString()`, it will work fine
Read more about [Double.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: toString() doesnot convert the figure to words. I want it in words not the figure just casted as string.

Comment: You can override ToString by yourself